# Busbar short circuit rating vs. cubicle rating

Tags: high-voltage, protection, power-engineering

First: This question is about medium and high voltage switchgear, not electronics.

A 7,2 kV switchgear has a short circuit current rating of `Ik = 40kA/3 s`. The cubicles however have ratings such as `40kA/1s` and `8kA/2s`. The ratings at the different locations are shown below.

What puzzles me is that a short circuit in both locations will be equal, as there are no sources or limiting components in between.

The sub-transient short-circuit current will be Ik'' = 34kA in the facility I'm looking at.

How can you have 8kA/2s equipment connected to a 40kA/3s busbar? Wouldn't the bottom part be destroyed by a short circuit of 40 kA (100 kA peak)?

Comments in advance:

- Yes, the short-circuit current will be lower after 2 seconds, but the ratings are only given as peak (force) and thermal (1-3 seconds), so that's what we have to work with
- Yes, breakers will cut the power long before 2 seconds, but these are the ratings so the question still stands.

[image]

Comment: Depens on where the short happens i guess. If the short happens in the 40kA/3s "part", the 8kA/2s "part" is not troubled by it. If the short happens in the 8kA/2s "part", there should be additional protection to prevent damage. E.g multiple of these 8kA/2s "parts" are connected in parallel to the 40kA/3s part and a single 8kA/2s failure should not cripple the others by "blowing" the 40kA/3s part

Comment: The circuit breaker/fuse is in the "apparatus compartment". But that is rated for 8kA/2s. There's nothing in parallel. The cabinet above is for one feeder/cable and there are 10-20 of these cabinets next to each other.

Comment: The busbar on top is obviously larger since the load current is much higher, but the fault current is equal on both sides.

Comment: Where did the drawing come from?

Comment: [ABB catalogue](https://search.abb.com/library/Download.aspx?DocumentID=1VCP000138&LanguageCode=en&DocumentPartId=&Action=Launch). I've added the ratings and arrows based on the ratings listed in the documentation from my customer. I can't share that information.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, ABB Unigear ZS1! I'd recognise it anywhere. :)

[image]

---

I strongly suspect that the 8 kA / 2 sec rating relates to the **black insulated fly leads which connect to the voltage transformers**.

[image]

The cable connection bars are part of the *main circuit* as defined by IEC 62271.200 and are type tested to *"withstand the rated peak and the rated short-time withstand currents"* as per IEC 62271.200 s7.6. The main circuit is defined as *"all the high-voltage conductive parts of an assembly included in a circuit **which is intended to carry the continuous current**."*

The type test is arranged so that *"...the most onerous conditions are obtained concerning the maximum lengths of unsupported conductors, configuration of the conductors and connections within the equipment, and the assigned rated values."*

The type test specifically excludes *"Connections to auxiliary devices (such as voltage transformers...)"* which are *"not part of the main circuit"*.